# How do you store keys in Mongodb with a '.' in them

Tags: mongodb

I need to have key fields with a '.' in them. Is there a way to do it? (I am unable to encode them)

Comment: There are some good solutions given here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name