# How do ReactionEmojis work in discord4j 3.1.0

Tags: java, discord, discord4j

I'm currently working on a bot with discord4j where I want to add a reaction(emoji) to a message.
But i have no clue, how to use the addReaction() method and every example i find is using an older version.
In earlier versions of dicord4j you could give a string of the unicode representation of the emoji as the parameter, but now it just takes in an object of the type ReactionEmoji. I looked at its methods nothing really makes sense except the ReactionEmoji.unicode(String raw) but then i get the error-message "unknown emoji". As input of the string i tried the unicode, the actual emoji itself, and i went into debug mode, added a reaction to a message, then took the reaction in debug mode, and copied the raw value of the reaction, pasted it as the input parameter of the unicode() mehtod , but it still didn't recognize it as an emoji.
Is there some documentation i can't find?
My code :

```
Message msg = channel.createMessage("Test").block();
msg.addReaction("U+2B06").block();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a [unicode escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522770/unicode-escape-syntax-in-java) instead:

```java
channel.createMessage("Test")
       .flatMap(msg -> msg.addReaction(ReactionEmoji.unicode("\u2B06")))
       .subscribe();
```

For documentation refer to [addReaction](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.discord4j/discord4j-core/latest/discord4j/core/object/entity/Message.html) and [ReactionEmoji](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.discord4j/discord4j-core/latest/discord4j/core/object/reaction/ReactionEmoji.html)

Comment: I tried using this to make a reactionAddEvent and Im getting compile errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767618/discord4j-no-instances-of-type-variables-r-exist-so-that-void-conforms-to-m

Answer (score 1):

For multiple reactions

```
 channel.createMessage("Test").flatMap(msg -> 
 msg.addReaction(ReactionEmoji.unicode(""))
                    .then(msg.addReaction(ReactionEmoji.unicode(""))))
.subscribe();
```