# Sanitize object literal in javascrtipt?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Given the following object:

```
var object = {
  'name': {
    test: 'one'
  },
  'test.two': 'test',
  'test.three.*': 'tes.two',
  'testfour': {
    'test.five': {
      'test.six': 'lorem ipsum'
    }
  } 
};
```

How do I replace all of the . in the keys sanitizing the object so as to insert it into a mongodb, is there a santize method I can use?

Comment: spaces underscores anything really... I'm basically trying to insert it into a mongodb and it' failing giving me:  Error: key test.* must not contain '.'

Comment: yeah I 'm looking through threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name
I'll mark this as a duplicate :D