# MongoDB Insert key with '$' (dollar)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to insert a collection with a json object containing a key which starts with '`$`' (for instance: '`$count`'). I read the mongodb v3.0 [FAQ's](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/faq/developers/#faq-dollar-sign-escaping) and they have mentioned it is not such a key. Is there any roundabout way insert such a key and retrieve it back?

Comment: I've provided a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name/52651208#52651208

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Field names cannot contain dots (i.e. .)
>   or null characters, and they must not start with a dollar sign (i.e.
>   $).](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)

---

> [In some cases, you may wish to build a BSON object with a
>   user-provided key. In these situations, keys will need to substitute
>   the reserved $ and . characters. Any character is sufficient, but
>   consider using the Unicode full width equivalents: U+FF04 (i.e. “＄”)
>   and U+FF0E (i.e. “．”).](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/faq/developers/#dollar-sign-operator-escaping)

Is not recomanded but you can try this:

```
dollar = "\uFF04";
＄
dot = "\uFF0E"
．

db.test.save({[dollar]:dot})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
db.test.save({[dot]:dollar})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58256b0f9934a5d1c696c456"), "＄" : "．" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58256d359934a5d1c696c457"), "．" : "＄" }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the snippet on how we can use?

Comment: Essentially you go through all your values converting $ or . to it's unicode representation as shown in the snippet

Comment: That is not the "true" dollar character. The usual dollar character is "\u0024", while the character "\uFF04" is a character "similar" to the "true" dollar character. Hence, if you want to store some working update queries in a collection, such as { $set: { name: 'Gianni' } }, you can not, because with that character they would not work. Also try to do ('\uFF04" === '$') in a js console and it will return false.