# Any work around to insert field in mongodb starting with $ sign

Tags: database, mongodb

I get dynamic query params in my REST api which contains keys starting with $ sign. for example $format and $cost.

I need to persist them into MongoDB.

When i checked for a solution in web, I come across a solution which says to convert my $ or dot(.) into equivalent unicode and save to database.

MongoDB documentation says that we can neither insert a field name starting with dollar($) nor field containing dot(.) in it.

Is there any other way to persist it into database? Because its a dynamic key and I don't have control over it.

Is there any inbuilt classes in Mongo Library which would internally convert my field into Mongo understandable format ?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542336/mongodb-insert-key-with-dollar

Comment: you can try to use key/value scheme : instead of having {"$keyName":"data"}, use {"key":"$keyName", "value":"data"}

Comment: @matthPen, can you elaborate a little ?

Comment: I've provided a solution that would take care of that here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name/52651208#52651208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following (not possible) document :

```
{
    $randomKey1 : 'data1',
    .randomKey2: {f1:'aa',f2:'bb'}
}
```

Instead of that, try to store to the following structure :

```
{
    fields:[
    {key:"$randomKey1", value: "data1"},
    {key:".randomKey2", value: {f1:'aa',f2:'bb'}},
    ]
}
```