# Document.parse() constructor not working for nested json array

Tags: java, bson, bsondocument

I have one extended json string.

```
{"_id": {"oid": "59a47286cfa9a3a73e51e72c"}, "theaterId": {"numberInt": "101100"}, "location": {"address": {"street1": "340 XDW Market", "city": "Bloomington", "state": "MN", "zipcode": "12427"}, "geo": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [{"$numberDouble": "-193.24565"}, {"$numberDouble": "144.85466"}]}}}
```

Trying to convert above json string to document in order to insert it into MongoDB. For this I am using *org.bson.Document.Document.parse(json_string)* constructor.

But the document I am getting after parsing, doesn't preserve the datatype inside `geo.coordinate` arraylist (Check below Document). While it preserve datatype of `theaterId`.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "oid": "59a47286cfa9a3a73e51e72c"
    },
    "theaterId": {
        "numberInt": "101100"
    },
    "location": {
        "address": {
            "street1": "340 XDW Market",
            "city": "Bloomington",
            "state": "MN",
            "zipcode": "12427"
        },
        "geo": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-193.24565, 144.85466]
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a potential issue in Document.parse() API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fields in `geo.coordinate` are starting with dollar sign `$`. In theaterId you have `numberInt`, while in coordinate - `$numberDouble`.

Check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542336/mongodb-insert-key-with-dollar) question for how to handle it depending on what you need. Considering, that it looks like `numberInt` satisfies your needs, you might just need to remove the dollars from field names.

**Edit:** After digging somewhat deeper into those docs, the one you provided as well, `{"numberInt": "101100"}` is not extended json with datatype, it's just a normal json object with property and value for that property. It would need to be `{"$numberInt": "101100"}` to be extended json. On the other hand `{"$numberDouble": "-193.24565"}` **is** extended. The datatype is not lost, it's parsed into `List<Double>`, since we know each element is of type `Double` the datatype can be reconstructed back.

If you take at `Document.toJson()`, under the hood it's working with `RELAXED` output mode, which will output coordinates as you are seeing them - `[-193.24565, 144.85466]`. If you provide `EXTENDED` output mode, for example like this:

```
JsonWriterSettings settings = JsonWriterSettings.builder().outputMode(JsonMode.EXTENDED).build();
System.out.println(document.toJson(settings));
```

then the datatype will be reconstructed back from the java type, and coordinates will look like so:

```
[{"$numberDouble": "-193.24565"}, {"$numberDouble": "144.85466"}]
```

In conclusion, there is no problem with `Document.parse("json")`, but there might be a problem with the json you are supplying to it.

**Edit2:**
As in showed in example, the datatypes can be reconstructed back from java types. I am not familiar with the way `collection.insertOne(Document.parse(json_string))` works under the hood, but if you don't explicitly specify the mode, it might be using `RELAXED` by default, instead of `EXTENDED`. The  docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/v4.4/fundamentals/data-formats/document-data-format-extended-json/) state - `This format prioritizes type preservation at the loss of human-readability and interoperability with older formats.`, so it would make sense. But this is just a **wild guess** on my part though, you would need to dig into docs to make sure.

Comment: Thanks @Chaosfire , meanwhile your answer seems to correct but my issue is due to MongoDB Extended JSON feature. [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)

Comment: @PiyushKumar There is no problem with the API, check the edit.

Comment: Hi @Chaosfire

I have one doubt. Suppose I have a json string which is in its canonical (extended) form. If I insert that json string from mongo shell using _db.collectionName.insertOne(json)_ then the type ( **"$numberDouble"** ) is preserved. While I insert the same string using java API _collection.insertOne(Document.parse(json_string))_ then it doesn't preserve type.
Please Note :- Consider above json string for now in this doubt (replace **numberInt** to **$numberInt** )

Comment: @PiyushKumar Things became too long for comment, so i made another edit, check it. I believe this is a matter of configuration, but might be wrong, since i am mostly speculating here.