# MongoDB: I want to store array object in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get array object from front side, and want to save it in collection using NodeJS, Mongodb.

My object is:

```
routerData={"User-Name":
    {"type":"string","value":["\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"]},
"NAS-IP-Address":
    {"type":"ipaddr","value":["10.1.0.1"]}
},
```

My collection schema is:

```
var model = new Schema({
routerData:{
    "User-Name": {
        "type": String,
        "value": []
    },
    "NAS-IP-Address": {
        "type": String,
        "value": []
    },

},
});
```

I am trying with this code:

```
var obj = new objModel(req.body);
obj.routerData = req.body.routerData;
obj.save(function (err, result) {

});
```

i am getting this error:

```
"message": "Cast to Object failed for value \"{\"User-Name\":{\"type\":\"string\",\
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are experiencing? What did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have a property named 'type' in your schema you should specify it like this 'type': {type: String}.

Also your value arrays should have type: "value": [String]

Here is a working example.

```js
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
 routerData: {
  'User-Name': {
   'type': {type: String},
   'value': [String]
  },
  'NAS-IP-Address': {
   'type': {type: String},
   'value': [String]
  },

 },
});

var RouterData = mongoose.model('RouterData', schema);

var routerData = {
 'User-Name': {'type': 'string', 'value': ['\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000']},
 'NAS-IP-Address': {'type': 'ipaddr', 'value': ['10.1.0.1']}
};

var data = new RouterData({routerData: routerData});
data.save();
```

Comment: i am in trouble with this type data: 

var routerData = {
        
        "Attr-26.14559.10":{"type":"octets","value":["0x00000002"]}
    }

Comment: @HardikMandankaa what is the issue?

Comment: can you try to replace "routerData" value and test?

Comment: @HardikMandankaa did you extend the schema and added "Attr-24.14559.10" field to it?

Comment: yes. i added in schema. 
it is store in collection in this format: ""Attr-26" : {
            "14559" : {
                "10" : {
                    "type" : "octets",
                    "value" : [ 
                        "0x00000002"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },"

I need to it store like other value

Comment: @HardikMandankaa please check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name You might need to change the structure and say store parameters in array and have something like this routerData: [{parameterName: ''Attr-24.14559.10", type: .., value: ...}, ...]