# Convert JSON (key value has dot) to BSON using mongodb.util.JSON and mongodb.DBObject

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

```
String json ={"underlying":{"Not-included":"238","Apache-2.0":"1"}}  
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name Apache-2.0

How to replace dot easily using above parsing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB dot (.) in key name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name)

Comment: No @MarcTarin it is not duplicate I want to know is it possible to do in the above approach using some kind of mongo configurations that makes job  easy. mappingMongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("_");