# Mongodb insert error - Must not contain '.'

Tags: mongodb

I am inserting login tokens into my database, but I keep getting **'Error: key services.resume.appLoginToken.date must not contain '.'**
My code below is :

```
    if(!result.services.resume || result.services.resume.appLoginToken == null){
      var tokenStr = email + Math.random(1,100);
      tokenStr = Base64.encode(tokenStr);
      queryStr =  {
        "services.resume.appLoginToken.date": Date(),
        "services.resume.appLoginToken.base64Token": tokenStr
       };
       collectionUser.insert(queryStr, function(err, result) {
         if(err)
             {
                 console.log('Error:'+ err);
                 return;
              }
        });
     }
```

Any help would be great, thank you

Comment: have you tried `new Date()`?

Comment: I get all the right values, its just when inserting into the collection that the error comes up

Comment: `db.test.insert({services: {resume: {appLoginToken: {date: Date()}}}})` or just make your `queryStr` an object ie: `queryStr = { services: { resume: { appLoginToken: { date: Date(), base64Token: tokenStr }}}};`

Comment: [Dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) is for "query" or "update". Insertion of data is a completely different thing. This seems to be the point you are not understanding.  The naming of the variable as `queryStr` indicates this as well, since this is not a "query".

Comment: Hmm okay, do you believe I should just be updating my collection?

Comment: Ended up getting it with using update and $set, cheers.

Comment: I thinks is the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name
You are trying to insert object keys with dots: "services.resume.appLoginToken.date"
Should be something like "services_resume_appLoginToken_date"