# Mongo - finding records with keys containing dots

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Mongo does not allow documents to have dots in their keys (see [MongoDB dot (.) in key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name) or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286922/inserting-json-document-with-in-key-to-mongodb ).

However we have a huge mongo database where some documents do contain dots in their keys. These documents are of the form:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(2761632),
    "data" : {
        "field.with.dots" : { ... }
    }
}
```

I don't know how these records got inserted. I suspect that we must have had the `check_keys` mongod option set to false at some point.

My goal is to find the offending documents, to update them and remove the dots. I haven't found how to perform the search query. Here is what I tried so far:

- `db.collection.find({"data.field.with.dots" : { $exists : true }})`
- `db.collection.find({"data.field\uff0ewith\uff0edots" : { $exists : true}})`

Comment: So finally you'd like to get something like this: `{
    "_id" : NumberLong(2761632),
    "data" : {
        "fieldwithdots" : { ... }
    }
}` ?

Comment: All I want is to find all the records of the form `{
    "_id" : NumberLong(xxx),
    "data" : {
        "field.with.dots" : { ... }
    }
}`. Once found I can update them to remove the dots or replace them with something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to get your `data` in form of keys and values. Then you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) with [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/) to check if there are any keys with `.` inside of it . In the next step you can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to filter out those documents where remaining array is empty (no fields with dots), try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            dataKv: {
                $filter: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$data" },
                    cond: {
                        $ne: [ { $indexOfBytes: [ "$$this.k", "." ] } , -1 ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $ne: [ { $size: "$dataKv" }, 0 ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            dataKv: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HiXbFq5IynK)