# Use . in JSON key and not as property

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to update data in MongoDB using NodeJs, I want to use user email as key and an object as value, like

```
changes : {
    user@email.com : {
        //key value pairs
    },
    user2@email.com : {
        //key value pairs
    }
}
```

Problem is when I'm using this code

```
var query = {id:"01"},
update = { "$set": { } };
update["$set"]["changes."+ req.session.email ] = req.body; //This line is causing problem
model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, function(err, result){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Updated');
});
```

The `"changes."+req.session.email` is formed as `changes.user@email.com` and it is saved in MongoDb as

```
changes : {
   user@email : {
      com : {
           //data from req.body
      }
   }
}
```

The `.` in email is interpreted as `property`,
So how do I tell it to use `.` as `string` in `key` and not as `property`. I tried wrapping `req.session.email` in `[]`, didn't work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

I know I'm not supposed to use `.` in key names, but it is okay to use `string`, and I just want to use a string that has a `dot` in it, but I don't know how to make Node read it as a complete string.

Here is what I want:

```
changes : {
    "user@email.com" : {
        //key value pairs
    },
    "user2@email.com" : {
        //key value pairs
    }
}
```

What I'm getting right now is:

```
changes : {
   "user@email" : {
      "com" : {
           //data from req.body
      }
   }
}
```

`user@email` and `com` is interpreted as string, but not the `dot` in between them. How do I use it as **complete string**?

Comment: Hello Jazib, MongoDB doesn't support dot in the field object. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names

Comment: But exist some npm packets that can help you to convert '.' to another character to save in mongoDB

Comment: Hey @Cuchu, maybe you're right but I don't want "dot". I want string as key. I just want it to read the dot as part of a string.

Comment: `"Until support is added in the query language, the use of $ and . in field names is not recommended and is not supported by the official MongoDB drivers."` You can't do that at the moment.

Comment: @Herohtar but I can use anything as long as it is in a string, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB dot (.) in key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name)

Answer (score 0):

The [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#dollar-sign-operator-escaping) suggests replacing illegal characters such as `$` and `.` with their Unicode equivalents.

For example:

> In these situations, keys will need to substitute the reserved $ and .
>   characters. Any character is sufficient, but consider using the
>   Unicode full-width equivalents: U+FF04 (i.e. “＄”) and U+FF0E (i.e.
>   “．”).

Original answer and related discussion can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25937348/2520628)

Comment: So do I have to escape the `.` like `user@mail\uff0ecom` in my string? Will that cause any difficulties when updating or querying?