# Insert if data doesn’t exist in the document – How to do insert new field and data with Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to insert to new field and data in existing document, if there is no data in it.

```
 if (repoData.detailViewCounter == undefined) {
        console.log('create 0')
        Repo.findOneAndUpdate({
          'owner.login': userId,
          'name': pageId
        }, {
            detailViewCounter: 0
          },
          {new: true, upsert: true})
      }
```

So When condition like this, and there is no `detailViewCounter` field, insert new field with number 0.

```
{
  'owner.login': userId,
  'name': pageId
}
```

But When I run this code and check the MongoDB Compass, there is still no data.
And I also create repo schema `detailViewCounter` with `type:Number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- change in option `upsert: false`
- one major problem is field name `"owner.login"` this is causing the issue, this will search in object `owner: { login: userId }` but in actual we have string `"owner.login"`, so this is not able to find any matching document, and this will not update record.
- you can check after removing condition on field `owner.login`, it will work

```
Repo.findOneAndUpdate({
    'name': pageId
  }, 
  { detailViewCounter: 0 },
  { new: true, upsert: false }
)
```

Look at MongoDB [restriction on field names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names), and good [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name).