# pymongo converts . variables into a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am inserting the data to mongoDB collection through pymongo. I have logged all the information and data which is being sent to update_one statement.

Data which is logged just before update_one statement :

```
 data =   {'a': 'h9421976fc124d5756497d3b', 'b': 1611046532.4558306, 'kw_trigger_thing_name': 'ThingName.a', 'ThingName.a_capability_temperature': 44, 'ThingName.a_capability_humidity': '288', 'ThingName.a_kw_thing_name': 'ThingName.a'}
```

But when it got inserted into "test" then it got appended like this :

```
inserted_data = { "_id" : ObjectId("6005d317525e0d67866c564f"), "a" : "h9421976fc124d5756497d3b", "b" : 1611046532.4558306, "ThingName" : { "a_capability_humidity" : "288", "a_capability_temperature" : 44,"a_kw_thing_name" : "ThingName.a"}
```

Using this to update the document:

```
collection.update_one({"a": "h9421976fc124d5756497d3b"},{"$set": data},upsert=True,)
```

So here you'll see parsed data with same prefix keys ThingName. get converted into a dict in mongo collection with key as ThingName.
WHy this is happening and how can we override this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly valid. Because when you update with `thing.a:x`, then it will store as object `thing: { a : x}`

[Field names restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)

Though mongo supports dot in latest versions, `drivers` do not support them yet. Hence the conversion still happens.

[Another wonderful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name)