# Storing OpenAPI Specification Document in AWS DocumentDB

Tags: swagger, aws-documentdb

I am trying to store Open API Doc (Swagger Doc) in AWS DocumentDB which has following Json structure under path section of the doc.

It's failing to save the doc because of the periods in the key under "content", "application/vnd.hedtech.integration.v1.0.0+json". If I replace the periods with underscores it saves.
I'm able to save in MongoDB without replacing periods in the key but not in AWS DocumentDB.

What's the best way to handle this?

Thanks,

```
"responses": {
    "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "headers": {
            "X-Media-Type": {
                "description": "application/vnd.hedtech.integration.v6.1.0+json",
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "content": {
            "application/vnd.hedtech.integration.v1.0.0+json": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/api-name.json"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon DocumentDB doesn't support "." and "$" in the field names, per [functional differences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.field-name-restrictions).
See if some of the options in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name) can help you overcome this.